# Add contact details to header.php Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to add some contact details to the right of the logo on [this site](http://bristolbridalboutique.co.uk/).

At the moment it is displaying beneath the logo. I'd also like to change the font and colour to match the nav bar.

Here's the code for the header.php to show what I did to the site.
I'm also aware that Laura (the owner) should be using a child theme but her husband built the site and has already done a lot of work without a child so building one for this one change seems redundant?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js" >
<!-- start -->
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

    <!-- set faviocn-->
    <?php 
    global $pmc_data; 
    $favicon = ''; 
    if(isset($pmc_data['favicon']))
        $favicon = $pmc_data['favicon'];
    if (empty($favicon)) { $favicon = get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/favicon.ico'; }    
    ?>

    <!-- set title of the page -->
    <title>
    <?php
    global $page, $paged;
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
    bloginfo( 'name' );
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( 'Page %s' , max( $paged, $page ) );
    ?>
    </title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
    <link id="favicon" rel="icon"  type="image/png" href="<?php echo $pmc_data['favicon'] ?>">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> Atom Feed" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>" />

    <?php if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); }?>

    <!-- add google analytics code -->
    <?php       
    if(isset($pmc_data['google_analytics'])) 
    echo pmc_stripText($pmc_data['google_analytics']); 
    ?>
    <?php wp_head();?>
</head>     
<!-- start body -->
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <!-- start header -->
    <header>
        <div id="headerwrap" >
            <!-- fixed menu -->
            <div class="pagenav fixedmenu">
                <div class="holder-fixedmenu">
                    <div class="logo-fixedmenu">
                        <?php $logo = $pmc_data['logo']; ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php if ($logo != '') {?><?php echo $logo; ?><?php } else {?><?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png<?php }?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description') ?>" ></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-fixedmenu">
                        <?php 
                        if ( has_nav_menu( 'scroll_menu' ) ) {
                             wp_nav_menu( array(
                             'container' =>false,
                             'container_class' => 'menu-scroll',
                             'theme_location' => 'scroll_menu',
                             'echo' => true,
                             'fallback_cb' => 'ideo_fallback_menu',
                             'before' => '',
                             'after' => '',
                             'link_before' => '',
                             'link_after' => '',
                             'depth' => 0,
                             'walker' => new description_walker())
                             ); 
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- respoonsive menu for scrool bar -->

                </div>
            </div>  
            <!-- top bar -->
            <div class="TopHolder">
                <?php pmc_showTop() ?>  
            </div>  
            <!-- logo and main menu -->
            <div id="header">   
                <div class = "header-inner">
                    <div class="header-social">
                        <?php pmc_socialLink() ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="logo">
                        <?php $logo = $pmc_data['logo']; ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php if ($logo != '') {?><?php echo $logo; ?><?php } else {?><?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png<?php }?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description') ?>" /></a>
                            <div id="contact">
                            <p>07939598489</p>      <p>laura@bristolbridalboutique.co.uk</p>
            </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- respoonsive menu main-->
                    <div class="respMenu noscroll">
                        <div class="resp_menu_button"><i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i> Menu</div>
                        <?php 
                        if ( has_nav_menu( 'resp_menu' ) ) {
                            $menuParameters =  array(
                              'theme_location' => 'resp_menu', 
                              'walker'         => new Walker_Responsive_Menu(),
                              'echo'            => false,
                              'items_wrap'     => '<div class="event-type-selector-dropdown">%3$s</div>',
                            );
                            echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>,<br>,<div>,<i>' );
                        }?> 
                    </div>  

                <!-- main menu -->
                <div class="pagenav">
                    <?php 
                    if ( has_nav_menu( 'main-menu' ) ) {
                         wp_nav_menu( array(
                         'container' =>false,
                         'container_class' => 'menu-header',
                         'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
                         'echo' => true,
                         'fallback_cb' => 'ideo_fallback_menu',
                         'before' => '',
                         'after' => '',
                         'link_before' => '',
                         'link_after' => '',
                         'depth' => 0,
                         'walker' => new description_walker())
                         ); 
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>                  
            </div>  
        </div>          
    </header>
```

Comment: Suggested Reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it on the right side you can use

```
#contact{ float:right;}
```

and to align it with the rest you can add

```
margin-top:54px;
```

for the font/color you can add

```
font-family: "brioche-italic", georgia, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
font-size: 17px;
color: #94bfba !important;
```

Comment: it's css, you can put this in your themes style.css

Comment: I know it's CSS I was worried I'd put the <div> in the wrong place to start with. The CSS code doesn't seem to changing it at all?

Comment: Looking at the style.css source of the site, don't see an instance of #contact, you sure you saved it?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6d5334637cc24e1adfdda5ce010bd21e , must be since it works fine when i put it in there :P

Comment: Okay so now it's working but the logo is definitely being pushed left and is not longer centre aligned.

Comment: It's because the structure is pretty messy, gotta remove the absolute positioning on header-social, get #contact on same level as header-social and logo, remove the 100% width of the logo, etc